# How to invoke function by name in vue js 3 composition api inside <script setup>?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, quasar-framework

There is a function that receives a name of form submitting button (quasar framework), in vue js 2 options api i would use this keyword with [] and name of button to invoke so-called function, is there a way to do so inside script setup?

```
<template>    
<q-form @submit="submit">
...
<q-btn type="submit" name="save">Save</q-btn>
<q-btn type="submit" name="sendToDep1">SendToDep1</q-btn>
<q-btn type="submit" name="sendToDep2">SendToDep2</q-btn>

</q-form>
</template>

<script setup>

function submit(evt)
{
    // would like to use something like 
    // this[evt.submitter.name]()
    
   // don't want to use ifs
   if(evt.submitter.name=='save') { 
     save();
   }
   ...... 
}

function save() {
...
}

function sendToDep1() {
...
}

function sendToDep2() {
...
}
</setup>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `this` word from the code you've commented out ?

Comment: So how do I evaluate without object like `this`?  evt.submitter.name() says that evt.submitter.name is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to Options API, you can wrap your functions in an object and call them by referencing the object

```js
<script setup>
const methods = {
  save: () => {
    ...
  },

  sendToDep1: () => {
    ...
  },

  sendToDep2: () => {
    ...
  }
}

function submit(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault()
  methods[evt.submitter.name]()
}
</script>
```

Comment: Worked fine. But I left function declarations where they were and contracted methods object like: `const submitMethods = { save, sendToDep1, sendToDep2} `, and invoking works `submitMethods[evt.submitter.name]`